# Loop through excel spreadsheets in different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, loops

So one of you posted this code in a different question:
Dim wkbkorigin As Workbook
Dim originsheet As Worksheet
Dim destsheet As Worksheet
Dim ResultRow As Long
Dim Fname As String
Dim RngDest As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

```
Set destsheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set RngDest = destsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) _
                   .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
Fname = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/*.xlsm")

'loop through each file in folder (excluding this one)
Do While Fname <> "" And Fname <> ThisWorkbook.Name
    Set wkbkorigin = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & Fname)
    Set originsheet = wkbkorigin.Worksheets("1st")
         For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With RngDest

            .Cells(1).Value = originsheet.Range("D3").Value
            .Cells(2).Value = originsheet.Range("E9").Value
            .Cells(3).Value = originsheet.Range("D22").Value
            '.Cells(4).Value = originsheet.Range("E11").Value
            '.Cells(5).Value = originsheet.Range("F27").Value

        End With
        wkbkorigin.Close SaveChanges:=False   'close current file
        Set RngDest = RngDest.Offset(1, 0)
        Fname = Dir()     'get next file
Loop
```

End Sub

The problem is I can only get it look at the first sheet in every workbook and copy that data. I am trying to get it too look through every sheet in each workbook and copy data from the same cells. Is there anyway to do that. Thank you

Comment: Change `originsheet.Range("D3").Value` to `ws.Range("D3").Value` and increment the destination (e.g. `.Cells(1).Value`).

Comment: Jeeped, I guess Im missing something because it wont even compile now and  Can you direct to where this exact question is located at? So I don't waste anyone else time? Thank you

Comment: Click on the link provided in the top message.

Comment: I checked it out, mine compiles now but still only grabs data from the first worksheet.

Comment: My crystal ball is in the shop and teleporting to where you are working is so expensive now-a-days. Why don't you edit your post (or better yet, ask a new question) with the updated code instead?

Comment: One point you seem to be missing is that the question of '*how do I loop through each worksheet in a workbook*' has been asked and answered literally hundreds of times. Do some research, write some code and if you run into problems, ask a new question with specific information and error codes. (see [ask]) Saying '*it doesn't compile*' or '*it doesn't work*' is a waste of everyone's time including your own.

Comment: Point taken Understood